# ment.io - model is not updating on mouse

Tags: angularjs, mouse, mention

I am using ment.io plugin from http://jeff-collins.github.io/ment.io/#/examples with tinyMce for editor support.

All was well until i found that when i select menu item by using mouse, model is not updating automatically, though in editor it is showing selected text properly.

Further while investigation, found that model is updating when we do some key event inside editor after selection with mouse.

While select with arrow key and select using enter or tab, model is updating properly. This might be because, this is the key event which editor seeks in earlier case.

Here is link of fiddle for the scrnario https://jsfiddle.net/vikasnale/2p6xcssf/5/

```
<div ng-app="App">
```

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/tag-mentions.tpl">
  <ul class="list-group user-search">
    <li mentio-menu-item="Tag" ng-repeat="Tag in items" class="list-group-item">
      <span class="text-primary" ng-bind-html="Tag.name | mentioHighlight:typedTerm:'menu-highlighted' | unsafe"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</script>

<textarea mentio-id="'tinyMceTextArea'" ui-tinymce="tinyMceOptions" mentio mentio-typed-text="typedTerm" mentio-require-leading-space="true" ng-model="Content" mentio-iframe-element="iframeElement"></textarea>


<mentio-menu id="hastmenu" mentio-for="'tinyMceTextArea'" mentio-trigger-char="'#'" mentio-items="tags" mentio-template-url="/tag-mentions.tpl" mentio-search="searchTags(term)" mentio-select="getTagTextRaw(item)"></mentio-menu>

<br/>
<p>Output Model: {{Content}}</p>
```

```
angular.module('App', ['mentio', 'ui.tinymce'])
```

.controller("Ctrl", ['$scope', 'mentioUtil',
    function($scope, mentioUtil) {

```
  $scope.getTagTextRaw = function(item) {
    return '<i class="mention-tag-text" style="color:#a52a2a;">' + item.name + '</i>';
  };

  $scope.searchTags = function(term) {
    var tagsList = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.allTagList, function(item) {
      if (item.id.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase()) >= 0) {
        if (tagsList.length <= 5) {
          tagsList.push(item);
        }
      }
    });

    $scope.tags = tagsList;
    return tagsList;
  };

  $scope.allTagList = [{
    "id": "ctp",
    "name": "#ctp"
  }, {
    "id": "earningRelease",
    "name": "#earningRelease"
  }, {
    "id": "presssrelease",
    "name": "#presssrelease"
  }, {
    "id": "inversor-conference",
    "name": "#inversor-conference"
  }, {
    "id": "live release",
    "name": "#IACLive"
  }, {
    "id": "reval",
    "name": "#reval"
  }, {
    "id": "margin",
    "name": "#margin"
  }, {
    "id": "phonecall",
    "name": "#phonecall"
  }, {
    "id": "Q4",
    "name": "#Q4"
  }];

  $scope.tinyMceOptions = {
    init_instance_callback: function(editor) {
      $scope.iframeElement = editor.iframeElement;
    },
    resize: false,
    width: '100%',
    height: 150,
    plugins: 'print textcolor',
    toolbar: "bold italic underline strikethrough| undo redo",
    toolbar_items_size: 'small',
    menubar: false,
    statusbar: false
  };

}
```

]);

> Note : This behavior is observed while using ment.io with tinymce

can't figure out the fix for this..

Please advice...

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I have the same issue.

Comment: @ShayanKhan, unfortunately i could not get answer for that ...

Comment: What is strange is that this works on the demo, here: http://jeff-collins.github.io/ment.io/. I am doing a check as well but if you can also have a look, maybe we can both tackle this together lol.

Comment: Is there any progress for this situation ? I'm facing this issue too

Comment: Any way to overcome this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem and on search came across this post. Since there was no solution I thought I would dig deeper. Here are my findings, If you can add on top of this to find a solution it would be of great help.

(1) I am using MEAN framework with angularJS. And trying to implementMent.io with Tiny MCE

(2) **Question**: Why is it working with the codepen Ment.io example  and not working with the implementation in jsfiddle ..

**Answer or observation**,
In the codepen implementation if you see they have included the tinymce but have never used it with the div.

[image: Codepen implementation]

also they have implemented a directive with listeners that is applied with ment.io called "contenteditable" this helps in properly replacing the  values..

In the Jsfiddle example by Vikas Nale.  The  text area  includes the tinymce editor. So as soon as we apply the Tinymce editor the model stops updating on enter key or mouse click, a space bar has to be pressed inorder for the model to be properly updates.

[image: Example on jsfiddle with tinymce]

(3) **probable reason** Now I thought I will also add the contenteditable directive and it will take care of the events. But it seems that when we apply the tinymce editor, the mention menu, text area etc is placed in an iframe element. Because of which the events are not propagating correctly.

I also tried the Setup: option of tinymce.  but as soon as we start that the @ menu of Ment.io stops working.

[image: set:up option]

this is as far as I could understand. I need to implement this in a project so any discussion, hint, pointers are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The above issue of not getting up to date text from the assigned data model was solved for me by getting the data from active editor of tinymce instead of the data model assigned to ment.io text area (see the attached screen shot).